# JCodeModel method writing, issues with "new"

Tags: java, jcodemodel

Need help in converting the following piece of code to jcodemodel understandable format

```
@Override
    public final void blah() {
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        String xml = xstream.toXML(this);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... solved it... :)

```
JBlock block = jtoStringMethod.body();
        JVar line1 = block.decl(xstream, "xstream", JExpr._new(xstream).arg(JExpr._new(domDriver)));
        JVar line2 = block.decl(jmod._ref(String.class), "xml", JExpr.ref("xstream").invoke("toXML").arg(JExpr._this()));
        block._return(JExpr.ref("xml"));
```